# Algebra nuances when using Sine rule

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm solving a Side-Angle-Side triangle. I have the sine rule set up properly, but the answer key in my book has some questionable algebra.

$$\frac a{\sin(19)} = \frac {4.4}{\sin(61)}$$

the book simplifies this to:

$$\frac {4.4}{\sin(61)}\sin(19)$$

My work led me to the answer below

$$\frac {4.4}{\sin(19)}\sin(61)$$
Is this equivalent? If not, why cant sin be a factor in the numerator when theres a sin in the denominator?

Comment: $\frac{4.4}{\sin(61)} \sin(19) = \frac{4.4\sin(19)}{\sin(61)}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did your algebra incorrectly.

- a/sin(19)=4.4/sin(61)
- (a/sin(19))*sin(19)=(4.4/sin(61))*sin(19)
- a = (4.4/sin(61))*sin(19)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

What's the difference between
$$\frac{ab}{c}\quad\text{and}\quad \frac{a}{c}\times b\ ?$$
and how we calculate the product of two fractions?

Answer (score 0):

Take another look at your first equation, and keep in mind that $\sin(19)$ and $\sin(61)$ are *numbers* just like 3.21 or $x$.  So rules of multiplication apply for them just like they do for all other numbers.  Therefore, you solve for $a$ in that equation by multiplying both sides of the equation by *the number* $\sin(19)$ to get your book's answer.

The two expressions you have are equivalent.  Remember again, $\sin(19)$ and $\sin(61)$ are numbers, and behave just like all other numbers.